# How to detect Chromium-based browsers based on UA string

Tags: php, chromium, server-side, user-agent, browser-detection

Is it enough to look for the word "Chrome" in the UA string to determine if the browser is Chromium-based? Or are there non-Chromium-based browsers that use the word "Chrome" in their UA string that would invalidate this method of detection?

Comment: Considering most browsers allow you to simply spoof the UA string - what's the point?

Comment: I think you'll have to detect it by excluding other browsers. Look at https://user-agents.top to find all strings to exclude

Answer (score 0):

User agent parsing is not a reliable method of detecting a browser. Just see [this list](https://whichbrowser.net/data/useragents/index.html) for thousands of user agent strings that just mash all browser strings together. Mainstream desktop browsers usually do not do this but many mobile ones do, especially on Android. Also, it's trivial to spoof this the user agent string.

Compare:

```sh
curl --user-agent "UserAgentString" http://example.com
```

In almost all cases what you really want to do is [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection). However, this required JavaScript. But given that close to 100% of browsers used by Real People™ support JavaScript and have it enabled, this should only be an issue in edge cases.

Comment: I'm fully aware of feature-detection and why it's the preferred method to use. In this case, I need to determine whether a browser is Chromium based before I send the HTML to the client (specifically, whether to include an link preload tag for srcset images, something only chromium browsers support at present), and other than making use of browscap, I'm coming up empty.